# Failed try/catch for value undefined in JSON - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Hello I have a script js that connects an api and receives a json as return, and insert in database, however when this json has an `undefined` value, it fails, it stops being traversed by the loop `(for x in cards)`, even if it is inside of a `try/catch`. Any suggestions?

NOTE: The value that has `content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['assignees'][0]['fullname']`, as undefined and inserted, however after that the script and interrupted.

> content = `const content = await rawResponse.json();`
>
> data = `var data = Object.keys(content);`
>
> squads = `var squads = Object.keys(content[data]);`
>
> cards =  `var cards = Object.keys(content[data][squads][0]["cards"]);`
>
> index total = 184
>
> failed to = 77

Print values cards:

```
[
  '0',  '1',  '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',  '8',  '9',
  '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
  '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29',
  '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39',
  '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49',
  '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59',
  '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69',
  '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79',
  '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89',
  '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99',
  ... 85 more items
]
```

Script:

```
    for (x in cards) {

        const parameters = [

            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['identifier'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['title'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['description'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['status'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['priority'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['assignees'][0]['fullname'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['assignees'][0]['email'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['primaryLabels'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['secondaryLabel'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['swimlane'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['workstate'],
            content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['createdAt']

        ];

         res = await client.query(query, parameters);

         client.query(res, () => {

            try {

                console.log("Insert card: " + content[data]["squads"][0]["cards"][x]['title']);

            } catch (error) {

                console.error("Error: " + error + " - " + content[data]["squads"][0]["cards"][x]['title']);

            }

        })

    }
```

Output:

```
Index JSON: 76
Insert card: [WIN] Update version Windows
Index JSON: 77
Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined - [LZ] Clean /tmp/
Insert card: [LZ] Clean /tmp/
```

Comment: Why are you trying to log the same value that caused the error in the first place?

Comment: You shouldn't call `client.query()` a second time. The first argument to `client.query()` must be SQL, not a result object.

Comment: Because it must be inserted even if it contains the FULLNAME field, the other fields have values

Comment: Please note that all-caps and bold read as yelling to much of the English-speaking, online audience.

Comment: There's nothing about `fullname` in the code inside `try/catch`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I used bold and CAPS LOCK to highlight the important points

Comment: Use backticks to do code highlighting.

Comment: @Barmar What do you suggest ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok, I'll edit

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I don't even see where you're trying to read fullname inside the try/catch, so that error message can't be coming from there.

Comment: You're reading `title`, not `fullname`.

Comment: I have no idea what `client.query(res, ...)` is intended to do. `await client.query(...)` should set `res` to an array of results.

Comment: I just clicked the title to find out which CARD is showing undefined values

Comment: If anything is undefined, you would get the error when assigning to `parameters`, before the `console.log()` call.

Comment: What I would like to do is just insert the data even when there is a null or undefined value inside the array

Comment: What would you like to insert? If `content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]` is undefined, then NONE of the properties will exist.

Comment: How can I make sure that when try / catch is triggered, it just ignores the error?

Comment: The error doesn't mean that an individual property is missing, it means the whole object is missing.

Comment: How can I make him skip this card? If it is undefined, it simply does nothing, and continue to the next one!

Comment: Now I understand, so it means that everything doesn't exist, not just FULLNAME!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `try/catch` around the entire body of the `for` loop.

```js
for (x in cards) {
  try {
    const parameters = [

      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['identifier'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['title'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['description'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['status'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['priority'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['assignees'][0]['fullname'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['assignees'][0]['email'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['primaryLabels'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['secondaryLabel'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['swimlane'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['workstate'],
      content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x]['createdAt']

    ];
    res = await client.query(query, parameters);
    ...
  } catch (Exception e) {
    console.error(`Couldn't insert card ${x}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still got this output: Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined - [LZ] Clean /tmp/

Comment: How can I make sure that when the value is undefined, it simply ignores it and continues to go through the 184 values?

Comment: You don't need to insert it in the database, you can just ignore the ones that are undefined, discard them

Comment: OK, put that solution in.

Comment: Fantastic my friend, thanks for your help, I hope that one day it will reach your level of knowledge, congratulations !!!

Comment: `const row = content[data][squads][0].cards[x];`... _please_